# New Youtube embed options aspect ratio

Tags: youtube, aspect-ratio

I'm embeding this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=kzsBCriOrh8 on a site but I'm getting a square aspect ratio. As you can see, in Youtube the aspect ratio is widescreen with black bars to the sides. I want this same behavior when I embed the video.
I'm following the new embed params http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/player_parameters.html

I can't seem to find any option that I can add to this to control aspect ratio

`&iv_load_policy=3&rel=0&autohide=1&showinfo=0&theme=light&color=white&amp;wmode=Opaque`

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

I solved it!
http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=146402
And I also added a fixed width and height in my js script. It works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it! http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=146402. And I also added a fixed width and height in my js script. It works.

Answer (score 0):

The height and width are controlled by the `height` and `width` properties on the `iframe` that is used to embed the video.

Comment: The problem is I'm embeding it with WordPress and oEmbed and adding those options dinamically with a js script. I guess I'll have to add some options to the iframe in the script too...